# Undefined symbols for architectures x86_64

Tags: c, makefile

I'm new to programming and I'm struggling trying to compile some files.

I use this Makefile to compile my project

```
NAME    =   so_long

SRCS    =   gnl.c main.c mapdup.c utils.c

INC     =   -I include

CFLAGS  =   -Wall -Wextra -Werror -fsanitize=address $(INC)

LIB     =   -L libft -L ft_printf -L mlx -lft -lftprintf -lmlx 

MACOS   =   -framework Opengl -framework Appkit

OBJS    =   $(SRCS:.c=.o)

GCC     =   gcc $(OBJS) -o $(NAME) $(LIB) $(MACOS)

all : $(OBJS)
make -C libft
make -C ft_printf
make -C mlx
$(GCC)
@echo "Compilation terminée"

clean : 
rm -f $(OBJS)
make -C libft clean 
make -C ft_printf clean
make -C mlx clean

fclean : 
make -C . clean
make -C libft fclean
make -C ft_printf fclean
rm $(NAME)

re :    make -C . clean
    make -C . fclean
    make -C . all
```

and here is what the compiler tells me

```
make -C libft
make[1]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
make -C ft_printf
make[1]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
make -C mlx
make[1]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
gcc gnl.o main.o mapdup.o utils.o -o so_long -L libft -L ft_printf -L mlx -lft -lftprintf -lmlx  -framework Opengl -framework Appkit
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "___asan_handle_no_return", referenced from:
      _ft_mdup in mapdup.o
      _exit_err in utils.o
  "___asan_init", referenced from:
      _asan.module_ctor in gnl.o
      _asan.module_ctor in main.o
      _asan.module_ctor in mapdup.o
      _asan.module_ctor in utils.o
  "___asan_option_detect_stack_use_after_return", referenced from:
      _get_next_line in gnl.o
  "___asan_register_image_globals", referenced from:
      _asan.module_ctor in utils.o
  "___asan_report_load1", referenced from:
      _get_next_line in gnl.o
      _ft_read in gnl.o
  "___asan_report_load4", referenced from:
      _ft_mdup in mapdup.o
      _nb_of_line in mapdup.o
      _map_to_buffer in mapdup.o
  "___asan_report_load8", referenced from:
      _map_to_buffer in mapdup.o
      _free_table in utils.o
      _printf_tab in utils.o
  "___asan_report_store1", referenced from:
      _get_next_line in gnl.o
      _ft_read in gnl.o
  "___asan_report_store8", referenced from:
      _map_to_buffer in mapdup.o
  "___asan_stack_malloc_0", referenced from:
      _get_next_line in gnl.o
  "___asan_unregister_image_globals", referenced from:
      _asan.module_dtor in utils.o
  "___asan_version_mismatch_check_apple_clang_1200", referenced from:
      _asan.module_ctor in gnl.o
      _asan.module_ctor in main.o
      _asan.module_ctor in mapdup.o
      _asan.module_ctor in utils.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [all] Error 1
```

I think there is a problem with the way I'm linking all my files together but I can see what's wrong.
I have the necessary headers in the include directory and the paths to the libraries I need seems correct for me.

Hope you will be able to help me with this information.

I tried to compile my project with the Makefile I provided but there is an error in the last step of the compilation.

Comment: Looks like your compiling your object files with `-fsanitize=address` in your `CFLAGS` but then failing to link with matching options in `LFLAGS`.  It _might_ be enough to set `LINK.o = $(LINK.c)`, but I don't have time to check right now.

Comment: I remove -fsanitize=address and now it compile correctly, thank you.